# variables defined and called across different web pages using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to JavaScript and this site and am trying to make a username and password creator and log in. for now i am just using a premade username and password for now. i have tried to do this with JavaScript but my code wont work for me on notepad++. i have learned a basic understanding of jQuery as a last resort to get this mock up site to run. can you tell me if there is a way to do it with JavaScript and how and if not can you explain the code to share variables across two different webpages using jQuery. pleas explain in plain simple English because as i said i am new to JavaScript and brand new to jQuery.

here is where the username and password variables are defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>
create account
</title>


<script>
sessionStorage.setItem( "username1", ["bob", "sam"]);
sessionStorage.setItem( "password1", ["lol", "jk"]);
</script>


</head>

<body>

</body>


</html>
```

here is where i call those variables

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
log on page
</title>

<script type = "text/javascript">
var count = 2;

function validate() {
    var un = document.myform.username.value;
    var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
    var valid = false;

    var unArray = sessionStorage.getItem("username1");
    var unArray = sessionStorage.getItem("password1");

    for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
        if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
        valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        alert ("Login was successful");
        window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return false;
    }

    var t = " tries";

    if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

    if (count >= 1) {
        alert ("Invalid username and/or password. " +
               "You have " + count + t + " left.");
        document.myform.username.value = "";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
        setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
        count --;
    }

    else {
        alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
        document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
        document.myform.pword.value = "";
        document.myform.username.disabled = true;
        document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
<!--this-->
    <style>

    p.log_on{
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    left: 20px;
}
</style>





</head>


<body>

<!--here-->
<form name = "myform">
  <p class="log_on">
    ENTER USER NAME <input type="text" name="username"><br><br><br><br><br>
    ENTER PASSWORD <input type="password" name="pword">
    <input type="button" value="Check In" name="Submit" onclick="validate()">
  </p>
</form>
<!--to here-->

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: For one thing, you are assigning to `unArray` twice, and to `pwArray` never. For another, I hope it's just a play project, since you can't have secure auth without a serverside component. (I also dislike `document.myform.username.value`, preferring `document.getElementById("username").value` and using `id="username"` instead of `name="username"`.)

Comment: i made the corrections and it still didn't work could it be that notepad++ does not understand sessionStorage.

Comment: Err, you lost me. Notepad++ is an editor, not a JavaScript execution environment. What you just said sounds to me like "I wrote all the notes, but when I hold the paper to my ear I don't hear any music". It is your web browser that understands `sessionStorage`, along with the rest of JavaScript.

Comment: then would my web browser understand sessionStorage?